# Want to apply Google Voice Assistant for media app(Music player App) like "play song in my app"

Tags: android, kotlin, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant, google-voice-actions

Want to apply Google Voice Assistant for media app(Music player App) like "play song in my app" tried https://github.com/android/uamp but this is also not working for for google voice assistant, UAMP app said they already apply Google assistant but not working while i installed app. How to apply Google Voice Assistant for media app(Music player App) already search   https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/overview , https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/interacting-with-assistant , https://developers.google.com/assistant but not helpful much.